# Alignment of a Continuous String with literal characters

Tags: java, string

I have a string in a java class. The string needs alignment for more readability as it is a continuous string and it has literal characters, like '\n' instead of the line breaks.

For ex: I do not get the line break but instead it is there as the character itself '\n' in the O/P and the entire O/P is a continuous string without proper alignment which makes the O/P difficult to read.

Sample O/P

```
'comp.db.actionserver.ActionServerResponse'::{
  action:'comp.db.workflow.actions.GetHostMemAllocInfo'::{
    rawOutput:'java.lang.String'::"meminfo::{\n  replicationStoreReader:'18700'::'malloc'::{\n    max :   9580544,\n    alloc : 6679840,\n    free :  348896,\n    frag :  5,\n  },\n  replicationStoreReader:'18700'::'ConnectionQueue'::{\n    max :   3563520,\n    alloc : 1412928,\n    free :  8384,\n    frag :  0,\n  },\n  replicationStoreReader:'18701'::'malloc'::{\n    max :   6295552,\n    alloc : 5779744,\n    free :  446176,\n    frag :  7,\n  },\n  replicationStoreReader:'18701'::'ConnectionQueue'::{\n    max :   1105920,\n    alloc : 44864,\n    free :  1061056,\n    frag :  2365,\n  },\n  storeReader:'30300'::'ConnectionQueue'::{\n    max :   2105344,\n    alloc : 548176,\n    free :  1557168,\n    frag :  284,\n  },\n  storeReader:'30301'::'malloc'::{\n    max :   20574208,\n    alloc : 19905408,\n    free :  668800,\n    frag :  3,\n  },\n  storeReader:'30301'::'ConnectionQueue'::{\n    max :   2105344,\n    alloc : 339632,\n    free :  1765712,\n    frag :  519,\n  },\n}\n2020-06-01T07:42:43.106253\tmain\t0",
    result:'java.lang.String'::"completed",
    returnMessage:'java.lang.String'::"GetHostMemAllocInfo: Action execution successful"
  },
  message:'java.lang.String'::"Action was executed succesfully",
  status:'comp.db.actionserver.ServiceResponse$Status'::"OK"
}
```

I'm looking to put proper alignment in place and replace the literal characters, so that '\n' character actually provides a line break and the tab spaces in the continuous string can be used to properly align the O/P. Something like this

```
'comp.db.actionserver.ActionServerResponse'::{
  action:'comp.db.workflow.actions.GetHostMemAllocInfo'::{
    rawOutput:'java.lang.String'::
    "meminfo::{
        replicationStoreReader:'18700'::'malloc'::{
            max :   9580544,
            alloc : 6679840,
            free :  348896,
            frag :  5,
        },
        replicationStoreReader:'18700'::'ConnectionQueue'::{
            max :   3563520,
            alloc : 1412928,
            free :  8384,
            frag :  0,
        },
        replicationStoreReader:'18701'::'malloc'::{
            max :   6295552,
            alloc : 5779744,
            free :  446176,
            frag :  7,
        },
        replicationStoreReader:'18701'::'ConnectionQueue'::{
            max :   1105920,
            alloc : 44864,
            free :  1061056,
            frag :  2365,
        },
        storeReader:'30300'::'ConnectionQueue'::{
            max :   2105344,
            alloc : 548176,
            free :  1557168,
            frag :  284,
        },
        storeReader:'30301'::'malloc'::{
            max :   20574208,
            alloc : 19905408,
            free :  668800,
            frag :  3,
        },
        storeReader:'30301'::'ConnectionQueue'::{
            max :   2105344,
            alloc : 339632,
            free :  1765712,
            frag :  519,
        },
    }
    2020-06-01T07:42:43.106253  main  0",
    result:'java.lang.String'::"completed",
    returnMessage:'java.lang.String'::"GetHostMemAllocInfo: Action execution successful"
  },
  message:'java.lang.String'::"Action was executed succesfully",
  status:'comp.db.actionserver.ServiceResponse$Status'::"OK"
}
```

I have tried the replace method in order to replace '\n' with a space. I have also tried the split method, however it simply puts the line break, but I still cannot make use of the tab spaces to align my string

Comment: Welcome to SO!!! Please do mention what did you try?

Comment: `OPstring.replaceAll("\\Q\n", "\n")`

Comment: Why not simply load a resource file into a string? Such a string literal in code is not really readable.

Comment: @Mandy8055 I have tried the replace method in order to replace '\n' with a space. I have also tried the split method, however it simply puts the line break, but I still cannot make use of the tab spaces to align my string

Comment: @RahulSharma you should always add these tries in your question; as these are norms of asking question on SO. If you don't then your question may get closed or downvotes.

Comment: @Mandy8055 Sure, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks!